# Applying Polymorphism to PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

Lately I have been experimenting with the MVC design pattern (in PHP), but I'm having trouble with applying polymorphism in its models. I have coded some basic polymorphic classes in my computer science class at school, but they don't really apply to "real life".

For example:

```
class Animal
{
    var $name;
    function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal
{
    function speak()
    {
        return "Woof, woof!";
    }

    function playFetch()
    {
        return 'getting the stick';
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal
{
    function speak() {
        return "Meow...";
    }
}
```

**Now I'll get the the real question**

I'm working on a website for a school organization with user accounts. Because there will be many types of accounts, I would like to use this project as opportunity to apply polymorphism it a "real life" scenario. But I'm not sure where to place different types of functionality.

I have a basic outline of what I'm trying to achieve below. I would like some professional opinions/suggestions to improve my code and get a better grasp on polymorphism.

**Account Relationships**

1. Administrator **has** an account - can access admin panel view, and has the ability to edit user content through CRUD methods.
2. User **has** an account - views a profile when they log in. A user will have the ability to add competition awards, details about their projects, and a bio about themselves. (admins will have the ability to edit all of this)
3. Member **is a** user - members can only add content to their own profiles and nothing else.
4. Officer **is a** user - officers can access and update event calendars and news feeds, as well as update their own profiles.

Each of the classes will be a Model, so I will have the ability to access varying parts of the account hierarchy. What is the best way to structure the CRUD functionality of each account type?

Thanks.

Comment: What you have there are actually called "[domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject)". There are no "models" in MVC. Model (singular) is a layer. Also, from my personal experience: making inheritance-based authorization system is really terrible idea .. believe me, I tried. Oh, and look up [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). I get a feeling that you are looking to try to combine domain and persistence logic in single class. SRP will be what you end up violating.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I looked around Google and found this ["article"](http://blog.tekerson.com/2008/12/17/data-mapper-pattern-in-php/). Data mappers are definitely new for me, but from what I see, it's exactly what I'm looking for.